# Can the projective unitary group be realized as a matrix Lie group

Tags: lie-groups

Is the projective unitary group $U(n)/U(1)$ isomorphic to some closed subgroup of the $GL(n,\mathbb{C})$ (i.e., a matrix Lie group)?

Comment: By the way, as a consequence of the Peter-Weyl theorem, it follows that all compact Lie groups can be realized as matrix groups.

Answer (score 2):

The standard way: Take the Lie algebra of that group. It is finite dimensional. The group acts on it (adjoint action). This gives a [representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjoint_representation).